firebase_messaging: firebase_push_notification shows an empty notification while flutter app is in foreground
I have setup firebase push notification with firebase_messaging and flutter_local_notification (to show notification in foreground). push notification works fine in background but in foreground it shows an empty notification along with
an flutter local notification. How can we get rid of this empty notification.
This is my flutter dart code implementation for firebase_messaging:
Future<void> handleBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print("Title: ${message.notification?.title}");
  print("Body: ${message.notification?.body}");
  print("Payload: ${message.data}");
}

void onNotificationResponse(NotificationResponse payload) {
  final message = RemoteMessage.fromMap(jsonDecode(payload.payload!));
  FirebaseApi().handleMessage(message);
}

class FirebaseApi {
  final _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  final _androidChannel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high_importance_channel',
    'High Importance Notifications',
    description: 'This Channel is used for important notification',
    importance: Importance.high,
  );

  final _localNotifications = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  void handleMessage(RemoteMessage? message) {
    if (message == null) return;
    print(message.notification?.title);
  }

  Future initLocalNotifications() async {
    const android = AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_launcher');
    const iOS = DarwinInitializationSettings();
    const setting = InitializationSettings(android: android, iOS: iOS);

    await _localNotifications.initialize(
      setting,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: onNotificationResponse,
      onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: onNotificationResponse,
    );

    final platform = _localNotifications.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
        AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>();

    await platform?.createNotificationChannel(_androidChannel);
  }

  Future initPushNotifications() async {
    await _firebaseMessaging.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: false,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );

    _firebaseMessaging.getInitialMessage().then(handleMessage);
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(handleMessage);
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(handleBackgroundMessage);

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) async {
      final notification = message.notification;
      // final data = notification.android.imageUrl;
      message.mutableContent;

      final BigPictureStyleInformation? bigPictureStyleInformation;
      if (notification?.android?.imageUrl.isNotEmptyAndNotNull ?? false) {
        final image =
            await http.get(Uri.parse(notification?.android?.imageUrl ?? ''));
        bigPictureStyleInformation = BigPictureStyleInformation(
          ByteArrayAndroidBitmap.fromBase64String(
            base64Encode(image.bodyBytes),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        bigPictureStyleInformation = null;
      }

      if (notification == null) return;
      _localNotifications.show(
        notification.hashCode,
        notification.title,
        notification.body,
        NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            _androidChannel.id,
            _androidChannel.name,
            channelDescription: _androidChannel.description,
            icon: '@drawable/ic_launcher',
            sound: const UriAndroidNotificationSound('default'),
            styleInformation: bigPictureStyleInformation,
          ),
        ),
        payload: jsonEncode(message.toMap()),
      );
    });
  }

  Future<void> initNotifications() async {
    await _firebaseMessaging.setAutoInitEnabled(true);
    await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission();
    final fcmToken = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
    debugPrint('Token: $fcmToken');
    initPushNotifications();
    initLocalNotifications();
  }
}

in main.dart i have:
await FirebaseApi().initNotifications();
and in AndroidManifest.xml file:
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="high_importance_channel" />

I am trying to get rid of this empty notification while flutter app is in the foreground
